# Split View Controller not root controller

Tags: ios, iphone, memory-leaks, uisplitviewcontroller, uisplitview

I have been working on a method of converting an existing iPhone app to an iPad app. Amongst the various challenges that come with this I am trying to display a UISplitViewController in the app to display a Master - Detail arrangement that exists in the iPhone app.

I have considered changing the root controller to be a SplitViewController as Apple suggests but I have multiple master - Detail arrangements in the application and Apple doesn't explain how to have that arrangement with only one SplitViewController as the root (they do explain how to have multiple Detail views for one Master, but that is something different).

To achieve my aim I have done the following:
On my View that contains my main menu (my first page) I load the UISplitViewController on a button push in the following manner:

```
-(void)showSplitViewController
{
UIStoryboard *myStoryboard = self.storyboard;
UISplitViewController *splitViewController =(UISplitViewController *)[myStoryboard      instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SplitViewController"];

// Detail
UINavigationController *navigationController = [splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject];
DetailedViewController *detailViewController = (DetailedViewController *)navigationController.topViewController;
splitViewController.delegate = detailViewController;
detailViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;

// Master
UINavigationController *masterNavigationController = splitViewController.viewControllers[0];
MasterViewController *controller = (MasterViewController *)masterNavigationController.topViewController;
controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;

AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[appDelegate.window setRootViewController:splitViewController];

self.navigationController.viewControllers = nil;
}
```

This shows the UISplitViewController and all is well.

On the split controller detail view I have a 'Home' button which takes you back to the landing page (the one with the button that triggers the code above). This code looks like this:

```
-(void)goHome
{
    // Return to the root view.
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [AppDelegate sharedAppDelegate];

// Create the Home View Controller
UIStoryboard *myStoryboard = [UIStoryboard  storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard-iPad" bundle:nil];

HomeViewController *hvc =  (HomeViewController*)[myStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeViewController"];
hvc.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;

// Create the Navigation controller
UINavigationController *navigationController=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:hvc];

// Remove the current root view controller
[self.view.window setRootViewController:navigationController];

//[navigationController presentViewController:hvc animated:YES completion:nil];
UIViewController *currentViewController = [navigationController presentedViewController];
}
```

The problem is that doing this generates a memory leak that I do not have the skill to track down. If you repeatedly switch from the Home View to the Split View and back again the memory consumption just keeps climbing. I think that a view or something is not being released correctly but I cannot track it down.

Does anyone have any suggestion of what I can do please?

If I change all of my code so that the UISplitViewController is the root how do I make it work with multiple master - detail arrangements? If this is not going to work how would you suggest I straighten out my code above please?

Comment: I don't see anything in this code that would cause a leak, unless it has something to do with the managed object context. You have both your master and detail view controllers embedded in navigation controllers, so you can navigate through as many masters and details as you want -- I don't understand why you have a problem with that given your structure. What function does the initial controller have in this app? Could you make that one, one of the details or masters (instead of changing the root view controller of the window)?

Comment: Hello and thank you for your comment. The initial view controller is a menu and restricts access to the other views (master - detail included) based on login status. The view also takes you to other views such as a screen that connects to your camera allowing you to scan QR Codes or barcodes which I cannot really stick inside the Master - Detail pages. It does mean that I need the Detail - Master to be a part of the system, not the root of the system.

Comment: Without knowing more about your workflow, it's hard to make specific recommendations, but you might consider whether it works to make the split view controller the (permanent) root view controller, and present that initial controller in the viewDidAppear method of the master view controller. Doing that (with no animation) will make it so that controller appears first. You could present other controllers (like the QR code scanning one) from there, or dismiss it when the login is successful, taking you to the split view controller.